# move values array column to other array column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

After making a comparison between two arrays and getting an output with equal numbers in the two
arrays. I would like to make equal numbers move from other column

```
function myFunction() {

var Foglio1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Foglio1");
var Foglio2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Foglio1");
var scrittura = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Foglio1") ;

var colonna1 = [];
var colonna2 = [];
var i = 1;
var j = 1;

while(Foglio1.getRange(i,1).getValue() != ""){
colonna1.push(Foglio1.getRange(i,1).getValue());
i++;
}

while(Foglio2.getRange(j,1).getValue() != ""){
colonna2.push(Foglio2.getRange(j,2).getValue());
j++;
}

var riga = 1 ;
var colonna = 5 ;

// da qua non so come iniziare il ciclo di confronto e lo spostamento dei specifici valori che sono uguali tra loro
for ( var x=0 ; x < colonna1.length ; x++){
for ( var z=0; z < colonna2.length ; z++){
if ( colonna1[x]== colonna2[z]){
colonna1.splice( riga , colonna ).setValue(colonna1[x]);
riga++;
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to find the common elements between two columns and paste them in another column.

Your code is quite inefficient for three main reasons:

- You don't follow the [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices), namely you are iteratively using `GAS` methods like `getValue` or `setValue` when you can simply use batch operations.
- Unnecessary loops could be replaced by more modern JavaScript methods to gain some boost in performance.
- You repeat the same code multiple times, for example `Foglio1`, `Foglio2` and `scrittura` are referring to the same sheet.

### Code snippet:

```
function myFunction(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const fg = ss.getSheetByName('Foglio1');
  const colonna1 = fg.getRange('A1:A').getValues().flat().filter(v=>v!='');
  const colonna2 = fg.getRange('B1:B').getValues().flat().filter(v=>v!='');
  const colonnaCommon = colonna1.filter(v => colonna2.includes(v)).map(v=>[v]);
  fg.getRange(1,5,colonnaCommon.length,colonnaCommon[0].length).setValues(colonnaCommon); 
  fg.getRange('A1:A').clearContent();
}
```

**Sheet used for the code snippet:**

[image]

**References:**

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)